# Can't install npm package vue-select

Tags: npm, vuejs3

I am trying to install vue-select to my Vue 3 project but error arises

[here is the screen of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve2tz.png)

Command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps were unsuccessful
Hope you can help with it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not compatible with Vue 3 yet